# how to share facebook image with redirect link to playstore in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

> Here is my code is working properly while i am sharing the image and i need to share the image with redirect link of palystore app.

```
public void shareFacebookUsingGraph(){

        ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "books.book")
        .putString("og:title", "title")
        .putString("og:description", "desc")
        .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
        .build();

        // Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.message_box);

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File image_file = new File(sd, "sharing_event.jpg");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(bitmap_image)
        .setUserGenerated(true)
        .build();

        // Create an action
        ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("books.reads")
        .putObject("book", object)
        .putPhoto("image", photo)
        .build();

        ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
        .setAction(action)
        .build();

        ShareDialog.show(FinalCardView.this, content);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Define variables here.
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
        ShareDialog shareDialog;

        CallbackManager callbackManager;

  shareDialog = new ShareDialog(getActivity());
    //code where you wanna share you image.
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {

                                    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                            .setContentTitle("TITLE")
                                            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("IMG_URL"))

                                            .setContentDescription("Description")
                                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("PLAY_STORE_URL"))
                                            .build();

                                    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                                }

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

                shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                        //System.out.println("onSuccess");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        //System.out.println("onCancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        //System.out.println("onError" + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Siddique.....I wanna share image from sdcard so your code is only working for the image already hosted in the server...

Comment: If you are looking for link, then you have to use ShareLinkContent.